# Android Studio - Gradle generate specific javadoc files

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, javadoc

I need to generate some javadoc for a project that contains 3 modules, and I only need specific files from each module.

In Android Studio I can go Tools -> Generate JavaDoc and then set custom scope, and selectively choose the files I want and it aggregates them into a single javadoc folder, but this won't work for our automated build.

I can't figure out how to do this on the gradle command line?

Every example is some variation of this task

```
task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath+=project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    destinationDir = file("../javadoc/")
    failOnError false
}
```

This generates the javadoc for the entire module.  I can't figure out how to get only the files I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can do it the following way

```
task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    destinationDir = file("../javadoc/")
    include("**/ClassFile1.java")
    include("**/ClassFile2.java")
    failOnError false
}
```