# JavaDoc, how to generate documents via gradle task for specific classes?

Tags: android, gradle, javadoc

I investigated this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004765/android-studio-gradle-generate-specific-javadoc-files), but it doesn't help me.

My task is to generate javadoc only for specific classes.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java/com/project/module'
        }
    }
}

task javadocApi(type: Javadoc) {
    source = sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs()
    destinationDir = file("../javadoc/")
    include("**/ClassObject.java")
    include("**/ClassListener.java")
    failOnError true
}
```

When I run the task `javadocApi` I get this error:

> **error: package android.app does not exist for whole code in these classes ClassObject and ClassListener**
>
> [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Javadoc generation failed. Generated Javadoc options file (useful for troubleshooting): '/Users/user/Documents/Projects/project/Developement/Sources/moduleaandroid/android/build/tmp/javadocApi/javadoc.options'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some attempt I found this solution:

```
 task generateApiDoc(type: Javadoc) {
    failOnError false
    final Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
    final def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
    options.bootClasspath(new File(sdkDir + "/platforms/android-30/android.jar"))
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    classpath += configurations.compile
    destinationDir = file("../release/Resources/JavaDoc")
    include("**/ClassName.java")
    include("**/ClassName.java")
}
```